# Tweet in Action Script 3 loading

Tags: action

I am new to ActionScript 3 and got the following question:

I am trying to rebuild a AS3 code to load my Tweets to my website. In the original file I got a link to a XML file that gets the link of my tweets. But I want to make the connection without the XML file. So in my AS3 code I want to make the link to my tweets

Can someone help me with this to make the link in my AS3 code?

This is my current AS3 file with a settingsLoader to my settings.xml. Can someone tell me what to change and were I need to place my link?

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
import flash.errors.IOError;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;


stop();

var myXML:XML;
var settingsLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var twitterUrl:String="";
var tweetNumber:int=0;
var myData:Object;
var oldData:Object;
var tweets:Object;
var myLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
var rnd=new Array;
var oldXML:XML;
var newTweet:String="";
var arrTweets=new Array;
var totalTweets:int=0;

settingsLoader.load(new URLRequest("settings.xml"));
settingsLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,processSettings);

function processSettings(e:Event):void{
    myXML=new XML(e.target.data);
    twitterUrl=myXML.twitUrl;
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest(twitterUrl));
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,processJSON);
}

function processJSON(e:Event):void{
    myData=JSON.decode(e.target.data);
    if(myData.success){
        sortTweets(myData.data);
    }

}
function sortTweets(jData:Object){

    tweets=jData;
    rnd=between(0,myData.count-1);
    totalTweets=myData.count;

    trace(rnd);
    for(var j=0;j<=myData.count-1;j++){
        var tmpMessage=tweets[rnd[j]].text;
        var tmp="";
        tmp=tmpMessage.split(" ");
        newTweet="";
        for(var i:int = 0;i<tmp.length;i++){

            if(tmp[i].substring(0,1)==="#"){
                tmp[i]="<font color='#EA1111'>"+tmp[i]+"</font>";
                newTweet+=tmp[i]+" ";
            }else if((tmp[i].substring(0,4)==="http")||(tmp[i].substring(0,3)==="www")){
                //niets doen
            }else{
                newTweet+=tmp[i]+" ";
            }
        }
        var tweet:Object=new Object;
        tweet.tHandle="@"+tweets[rnd[j]].senderScreenName;
        tweet.tMessage=newTweet;
        arrTweets.push(tweet);
    }
    for(var k:int = 0;k<arrTweets.length;k++){
        trace(arrTweets[k].tHandle);
    }
    play();
}




function between(startNumber:int, endNumber:int):Array{
        var baseNumber:Array = new Array();
        var randNumber:Array = new Array();
        for(var i:int =startNumber; i<=endNumber; i++){
            baseNumber[i] = i;
        }
        for(i=endNumber; i>startNumber; i--){
            var tempRandom:Number = startNumber + Math.floor(Math.random()*(i - startNumber));
            randNumber[i] = baseNumber[tempRandom];
            baseNumber[tempRandom] = baseNumber[i];                                                                                                                                                                             
        }
        randNumber[startNumber] = baseNumber[startNumber];
        return randNumber;      
}       
//niet meer nodig
function processLocalSettings(e:IOErrorEvent):void{

    settingsLoader.load(new URLRequest("settings.xml"));
    settingsLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,processSettings);
}
```